# Information about using Gatsby for a dynamic application

Tags: gatsby

I'm looking for the best starter kit for an application I would like to start building with React, Redux and SSR.

Since it is very hard to start from scratch I started looking at next.js and gatsby.

Actually I started to implement my basic code in both of those with very nice results.

Now before going ahead with more "complex" stuff I would like to better know how and if Gatsby support dynamic urls.

My app should:

1. Signup or Login users in;
2. Display a personal control panel for each registered user;
3. Create a specific public profile page of each registered user.

Achieving the first 2 points is quite easy but what I'm trying to understand is how to handle a page with a routing that should be something like: `/users/:id/:nickname`.

I'm looking around on Google and I see weird things to do with cron job tasks to re-build the app every x minutes (something I would not like to do at all).

Then I have found the [Bound Action Creators](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/bound-action-creators/) by looking at the Gatsby documentation but as usual to understand a documentation 100% is always tricky: what is that? How and where to use that? Can I use the `createPage` method at redux level? Is it server side rendered?

Can someone tell me if this product is good to achieve what I explained above and maybe link some samples, tuts or small chunks of code to help me understand it before I start writing a lot of code that may be useless?

Cheers.

Comment: Gatsby fetches dynamic data into it's GraphQL store at build time, as I know. So you have to rebuild every time there is a change. I think you need Express as backend for your dynamic routing. Or React router could help you there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with next.js, but you can create dynamic URLs from data using the Bound Action Creator.  Here are the steps.

1. You need a data source in GraphQL.
2. You need to convert your data source into GraphQL.  If you have a GraphQL server, you can use an existing source plugin, gatsby-source-graphql.
3. You need to configure the plugin source in the gatsby-config.js
4. You need to configure the dynamic URL and page in the gatsby-node.js
5. Create the template page for the dynamic content and URL.

https://github.com/jlengstorf/gatsby-with-unstructured-data/tree/using-gatsby-data-layer
It is a gatsbyjs example site using the pokemon REST API.  It creates dynamic URL from the data using a custom GraphQL plugin that imports REST API.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/gatsby-starter-blog
It is a stater site, but it uses the local file system as the GraphQL source.  It is useful for understanding how the template and gatsby-node work together.

Good luck.